# How are walkers deployed to the surface

Tags: star-wars

In both ESB and TLJ, the Empire and First Order deploy walkers to attack the rebels. However, how they are deployed to the surface from the Star destroyers in orbit. How is this done?

Comment: The question of how they got to the surface in Last Jedi isn't a dupe, although the answer is the same

Comment: *"The journey ended in a huge hangar prepared for war. Dozens of TIE fighters were fueled and ready, tethered to their support lines. Troop transports waited to receive soldiers. **Scout walkers stood in front of heavier, four-legged war machines, which were attached to the drop ships that would bring them planetside**. And a full stormtrooper regiment stood in parade formation.*" - Last Jedi - Official Novelisation